# how to write >= eloquent database query in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to fire eloquent query in laravel 5.2

```
  Movies_showtimes::with('showdata','movie','cinema')->where(['cinema_id'=>$id,'show_date'=>Carbon::today()])->get();
```

This query fetches all movie showtimes for today date only. I want to fetch the movie showtimes for >= today but I am unable to fit >= symbol in where() clause in above query.

Help is appreciated. I tried doing like this but it didn't worked for me

```
  Movies_showtimes::with('showdata','movie','cinema')->where(['cinema_id'=>$id,'show_date','>=',Carbon::today()])->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
Movies_showtimes::with('showdata','movie','cinema')->where(
    [['cinema_id','=',$id],['show_date','>=',Carbon::today()]]
    )->get();
```

Comment: Movies_showtimes::with('showdata','movie','cinema')->where([['cinema_id','=',$id],['show_date','>=',Carbon::today()]])->get();          I was getting error when I used whereColumn